# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python

Este es el código que tengo. No consigo que funcione `if option == 1` se vaya a esas opciones.

El mensaje de error que me sale es el siguiente:

```
TypeError: eleccion_de_subsector() missing 1 required positional argument: 'eleccion_de_sector'
```

El código

```
def eleccion_de_subsector(eleccion_de_sector):
    opcion = eleccion_de_sector
    input_ok = False
    while not input_ok:
        print("¿A qué subsector pertenece la empresa?")
        print("Las opciones que tiene son: ")
        if opcion == 1:
            print("1 Healthcare")
            print("2 Consumer Defensive")
            print("3 Utilities")
            user_selection = input("Por favor, seleccione una opción: ")
            if user_selection in ("1", "2", "3"):
                input_ok = True
            else:
                print("Incorrecto, debe elegir un valor del 1 al 3")
            return user_selection
        return 0
        
        
#eleccion_de_subsector(eleccion_de_sector)
eleccion_de_subsector = eleccion_de_subsector()
```

Comment: Fíjate que llamas la función "eleccion_de_subsector" sin ningún argumento cuando la defines con uno "eleccion_de_subsector(eleccion_de_sector)", entonces, simplemente añade el valor, define la función sin parámetros o haz que el parámetro sea opcional.

Answer (score 0):

La función `eleccion_de_subsector` está definida con un argumento:

```
def eleccion_de_subsector(eleccion_de_sector):
```

y luego la llamas sin pasarle ninguno:

```
eleccion_de_subsector = eleccion_de_subsector()
```

Probablemente deba decir

```
eleccion_de_subsector = eleccion_de_subsector(1)
```